# Derive UDID from iPhone serial #

Tags: iphone, udid

the docs state that the iOS UDID is a hash derived from serial # and something else. Does anyone know - what else, and what's the hash algorithm?

The reason is, we have an enterprise database of work-issued iPhones with serials in it, and the software uses UDID to identify a phone.

Comment: My first thought (after good luck) is that you should contact Apple through your enterprise developer portal to attempt to get this information.

Comment: My faith in the collective wizdom of SO is that great. [schmoose mode off]

Comment: I feel you may be misguided (especially since my noob google-fu wasn't able to find jack about this subject; besides naysayers, of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

formula for udid described here: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/UDID

EDIT: pasting the formula here:

The UDID is being calculated like this:

- Create a 60-character long or 59-character long (on newer devices) text string (see below)
- Calculate the SHA1 hash of the text string. The result is the UDID.

To create the text string, append the following four strings:

- 11-character long or 12-character long (on newer devices) serial number (exactly like it is written in the Settings app)
- one of these:

  - (on older devices) 15-character long IMEI number (without spaces); empty string for iPod touch and Wi-Fi model iPads
  - (on newer devices) 13-character long ECID in decimal, no leading zeroes
- 17-character long Wi-Fi MAC address (letters in lower case, including colons); for the iPod touch first generation use "00:00:00:00:00:00"
- 17-character long Bluetooth MAC address (letters in lower case, including colons)

In short:

On the Verizon iPhone 4 and newer:

```
UDID = SHA1(serial + ECID + wifiMac + bluetoothMac)
```

All else:

```
UDID = SHA1(serial + IMEI + wifiMac + bluetoothMac)
```

Comment: Why the downvote for this. I thought this was a great answer and it was also the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're specifically asking about deriving the udid from other identifiers but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591972/using-udid-to-create-unique-user-identity?rq=1), if you want the UDID you can just use:

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Comment: I know that. Read the question: "the software uses UDID..."